# Problem Open PDF generated permission denied

Tags: android-studio, pdf

Tengo una aplicación que crea un pdf para luego abrirlo y poder verlo en la pantalla ... Funciona bien en algunos dispositivos, pero en algunos cuando se depura, el siguiente mensaje

```
05-22 11:38:43.105 9334-9334/desarrollos.lfpu.com.pos_connect W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Reporte.pdf/MisGenerados/Factura_de_venta_sistevar.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

El programa funciona en mi teléfono celular pero al probar en una tableta china el mensaje anterior

Código:

```
 private void generarPDF1(String htmlPDF){
    String tituloPdf="Factura_de_venta_sistevar.pdf";
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    String NOMBRE_ARCHIVO = tituloPdf.toString();
    String tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File pdfDir = new File(tarjetaSD + File.separator + NOMBRE_CARPETA_APP);
    if(!pdfDir.exists()){
        pdfDir.mkdir();
    }
    File pdfSubDir = new File(pdfDir.getPath() + File.separator + GENERADOS);
    if(!pdfSubDir.exists()){
        pdfSubDir.mkdir();
    }
    nombre_completo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + NOMBRE_CARPETA_APP
            + File.separator + GENERADOS + File.separator +NOMBRE_ARCHIVO;
    File outputfile = new File(nombre_completo);
    if(outputfile.exists()){
        outputfile.delete();
    }
    try {
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(nombre_completo));
        document.open();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.iconopdf);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image imagen = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        imagen.getAlignment();
        document.add(imagen);
        document.addAuthor("Sitevar_S.A");
        document.addCreator("Vendedor");
        document.addSubject("");
        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addTitle("Factura_de_ventas");
        String factura = htmlPDF;

        XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
        try{
            worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, new StringReader(factura));
            document.close();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PDF Generado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             mostrarPdf(nombre_completo,this);
            lanzarEmail();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Metodo para desplegar el PDF

```
    private void mostrarPdf(String archivo, Context contex){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Leyendo el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    File file = new File(archivo);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        contex.startActivity(intent);

    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(contex, "No tiene una app para abrir este archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

permisos en el  manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

El `LogCat` indica en el mensaje permios denegados:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Reporte.pdf/MisGenerados/Factura_de_venta_sistevar.pdf:
>   open failed: EACCES **(Permission denied)**

esto es relacionado al permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` que aunque comentas lo tienes especificado en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, el problema que tienes es que seguramente usas un dispositivo con android 6.0 o superior, por esta razón debes requerir el permiso manualmente.

```
            //Check permissions Android 6.0+
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                checkExternalStoragePermission();
            }
```

puedes usar este método, al aceptar el permiso tu aplicación funcionara sin problemas.

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {          
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } 
}
```

---

No es necesario declarar los permisos `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` y `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , únicamente necesitas: